# how many ways are there to choose a Board of Directors consisting of 5 people?

Tags: combinatorics

[image]

The answer is  D). I don't know how they arrived to that answer. please give me a hint.

Comment: Hint:  first choose the Vice presidents, then the Advisors, then choose the President.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: If you can answer the following questions, you can identify the factors in the correct answer.

- How many ways are there to choose the $2$ Vice-Presidents from the $n$ students?
- After you’ve chosen the $2$ Vice-Presidents, how many ways are there to choose the $5$ members of the Advisory Board from the remaining students?
- And after you’ve done all that, how many ways are there to choose the President?

Comment: i got the answer, but why did you first start with vice presidents?

Comment: @KapookyHandy: Because all of the choices for the answer have a factor of $\binom{n}2$: this is the number of ways to choose $2$ of the $n$ people, and since there are to be $2$ Vice-Presidents, this factor must correspond to choosing the VPs. Since they’re being chosen from the whole pool of $n$ students, we must be choosing them first. After they’ve been chosen, only $n-2$ students remain, so the next choice will be either $\binom{n-2}5$, the number of ways to pick the Board members, or $\binom{n-2}1$, the number of ways to pick the President.

Comment: Now i see how you solved it!

Comment: @KapookyHandy: Excellent!